# Can we merge two of more cells if a value is same rowwise in datatable or using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, datatable

This is how it should look In different number of orders if client name is same in next rows of same column then cells must merge

[image]

Comment: please show some example of your data as text and wanted result

Comment: You’ll have to show some code in terms of what you’ve already attempted for us to help you.